# How come the dimensions of the first Dense layer do not have to equal the dimensions of Flatten() in CNNs?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

From my understanding of CNNs, Flatten is used to go from 2D to 1D so that you can use Dense layers to perform classification. Also in my understanding, flattening results in the dimensions of the filter times the number of filters.

Why is it that after flattening, the first Dense layer does not have to have the same dimensions as the result of Flatten (which would be dims of filter * filters)? CNNs in which the first Dense layer has fewer or greater nodes than the dims of flatten will both work, but I have no idea why. Isn't flatten supposed to give you the inputs for the Dense layers?

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are talking about? To me it seems you have many misconceptions about how Flatten works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten does indeed flatten out your outputs to 1-dimension.

However, the dense layer it feeds into can be any size. The number of neurons in the dense layer(s) do not depend on the number of inputs they receive. This is a feature of traditional neural networks (multilayer perceptrons) and has nothing to do with the convolution operations or layers beforehand.

The design of the fully-connected part of the network, where the dense layers are, does not have a definitive solution, however there are [rules-of-thumb](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw) that can be followed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why does the number of neurons in the first dense layer not depend on the number of inputs it receives? I now realize I may be misunderstanding a crucial part of ANNs in general, but I thought each input value was used as an activation value for one input node, meaning there needs to be one node for each input value.

Comment: The neurons do not depend on the inputs because the inputs are not mapped one-to-one with the neurons. Each input can go to many neurons in the first layer (one-to-many).

Comment: Okay, great. So how exactly are the inputs mapped to the nodes in the first layer? Do all inputs go to each node? And then each node sums their inputs and puts the total input into an activation function to determine its output? Why is this process never shown in any tutorials (that I've seen at least)? Do you know of any good blogs/sources that explain this process?

Comment: Typically, each input maps to every neuron in the first layer - in any network I have designed, this has been the case. Each neuron's value is the sum of all inputs multiplied by their respective weights, plus a bias. This value is then squashed by an activation function to determine the output of that neuron. This question is diverging from the original so if you have a more specific question I'd recommend posting another question. And could you please select this question as answered.